# load external html into div at parent html

Tags: jquery, html, css, web-frontend

i load second.html into #divcontainer@first.html, and i want to load third.html to #divcontainer@first.html using the button within the second.html, while unload the second.html

i succeed loading the second html into first html using load().

i have tried using this in the second.html:

```
    $("#button").click(function () {
    $("#divcontainer".top.parent.document).unload("second.html");
    $("#divcontainer".top.parent.document).load("third.html");
    });
```

but doesnt work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmB3U.jpg "structure"

Comment: have you create a sample using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: i havent, coz it must create three html file.

Comment: html code structure which you use

Answer (score 0):

As the elements are dynamically loaded then you have to use event delegation:

```
$('#divcontainer').on('click', '#button' function () {
   $(this).parent().load('third.html');
});
```

and you don't need to `unload` anything as it will replace the existing content.

Comment: i tried this, but doesn't work. i put your script in second.html where the button is.

Comment: @kikisutanto you can use it on main page.